# Internationalize date formatting in Go

Tags: date, go, internationalization

I currently have the following markup in a Go template:

```
{{ .PublishedAt.Format " Jan 02, 2006" }}
```

I'd like to display it using this format, but in another language. Is this a feature built-in in Go? If not, what is the best practice to achieve this?

Comment: There's no support at this time and the time package doesn't seem easily extensible to me but I'm going to think about this a bit. If the arrays that held those strings were exported it would be super easy to modify by reassigning your foreign language version to that property. Hopefully I can find an alt that is similar because I think that's the only reasonable way of handling it. Otherwise you're gonna have a shit ton of mapping code that no one wants to deal with or maintain.

Comment: Basically you want a `map[string][]string` with the language as the key and the value being that languages equivalent to `shortDayNames` or whichever format const you want (you may need several of these, I'm referencing an unexported array in time that holds the Mon, Tues ect values) then you could set the language before doing the format call allowing you to reuse the massive switch logic that produces the formatted string. You may just want to take the source in time and make your own version with the added feature I describe.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal If something already exist atm, I'd favor that instead of reinventing the wheel. After investigation and your answers, I do believe it is not implemented at the moment. I'll look for packages. Otherwise, last option is to create one.